# Cant check checkbox on clicking li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to check a checkbox by clicking a `li`. The problem is, the checkbox is only checked when someone clicks on the `label`, not the full `li` (this is because the width of the `li` is longer than the `label`!

```html
<ul>
  <li><input id="a1" type="checkbox"><label for="a1">1</label></li>
  <li><input id="a2" type="checkbox"><label for="a2">2</label></li>
  <li><input id="a3" type="checkbox"><label for="a3">3</label></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to solve this problem using the Javascript below, however it still only checks the checkbox when the `label` is clicked.

```js
$("li").click(function(e) {
  var checked = !$(this).children("input").first().prop("checked");
  $(this).children("input").first().prop("checked", checked);
  $(this).toggleClass("selected", checked);
});
```

*Note: if possible, I would like to avoid Javascript and Jquery.*

Comment: Your current [code](https://jsfiddle.net/7tphdaLx/) works: https://jsfiddle.net/7tphdaLx/
What is the issue?

Comment: If you are trying to check the box by clicking between the bullet and the box, that won't work. As Ahs N said, the code works fine.

Comment: @Gerard With my solution, clicking on the bullet works too..

Comment: Add CSS `li{display:block;}` this will cover complete scope of li and click work perfectly :)

Answer (score 7):

**You don't need a script**. You can wrap the checkbox and all the `li` content with `label`. Give the label `display:block` so it will take the full width of the `li`. This way, the `li` will be clickable (like, not really)

```css
label {
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><label for="a1"><input id="a1" type="checkbox">1</label></li>
  <li><label for="a2"><input id="a2" type="checkbox">2</label></li>
  <li><label for="a3"><input id="a3" type="checkbox">3</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is the `for` attribute needed here for each `label`?

Comment: In that structure, on (the `label` wrap the `input`). I just followed the asker syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this;

Add class="myclass" to ul.

```
$('ul.myclass li input').click(
    function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution does use straight up JS but it's inline in the HTML, so nothing too complicated.

```
<li onclick="document.getElementById('a1').checked = !document.getElementById('a1').checked;">
    <input id="a1" type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation();"><label for="a1">1</label>
</li>
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/2v47Lwhb/

Answer (score 0):

1. use event.preventDefault() on the click event of the label.
2. And then use the css property *z-index:2* on the checkbox input so that the checkbox is in on top of the label layer.