# My HTML/CSS won't allow me to interact with my stylized checkboxes

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to stylize my checkboxes so you click the labels instead of having actual boxes, but I cannot select the checkbox  - the labels allow me to hover, but it doesn't appear I can interact with the checkboxes themselves. I wanted to have it so when you hovered/checked the box (which fills 1/3 of the area), it would be selected, and be white/green, but when I click, it does not seem to be checked. Where can I make it 'check'?

Here's what I'm working with (my actual code doesn't have the last header off to the side, which is strange, since I didn't change much anything from the original code):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
}

* {
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-align: center;
}

input::placeholder {
  text-align: left;
}

body {
  background: #62BF67;
  color: white;
}

input[type="password"],
input[type="text"] {
  border-top: 200px;
  border-left: 2px;
  border-right: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  margin: auto;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

form section {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form section div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px #FFF solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form section div:not(#BlockOne) {
  padding: 15px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#BLockOne {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#environs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

label:hover,
label:active,
label:focus,
input:checked {
  background-color: white;
  color: #62BF67;
}

#environs>li>label {
  display: block;
}

#environs>li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<form>
  <section>
    <h3 class="header">Login information</h3>
    <div id="personal">
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email - first.last@email.com">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" id="firstpass" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

  </section>

  <section>
    <h3 class="header">One</h3>
    <div id="BlockOne">
      <input type="password" id="secpass" placeholder="Second Password">
      <ul id="environs">
        <li><label for="env1"><input type="checkbox" name="env" id="env1" value="env1">env1</label></li>
        <li><label for="env2"><input type="checkbox" name="env" id="env2" value="env2">env2</label></li>
        <li><label for="env3"><input type="checkbox" name="env" id="env3" value="env3">env3</label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h3 class="header">Two</h3>
    <div id="BlockTwo">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Run">
</form>
```

Edit: I was attempting to recreate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996999/cant-check-checkbox-on-clicking-li)

Comment: Your checkbox display is set to none.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you remove `display:none` from the check box you can see that clicking works. You can not set the checkbox to checked when hovering the label with CSS. That isn't how CSS works, it applies styling base on certain responses, it doesn't change the state of elements. If you want to have the check box checked in response to a hover event, you will need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This may be , or at least partially be, what you're after.

There is no parent CSS selector, so you need to refactor your HTML a little like the following, putting the checkbox **before** the label

```
<input type="checkbox" name="env" id="env1" value="env1"><label for="env1">env1</label>
```

Now you can style the label using the adjacent sibling combinator `+`

```
input:checked + label
```

Full Version:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
}

* {
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-align: center;
}

input::placeholder {
  text-align: left;
}

body {
  background: #62BF67;
  color: white;
}

input[type="password"],
input[type="text"] {
  border-top: 200px;
  border-left: 2px;
  border-right: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  margin: auto;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

form section {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form section div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px #FFF solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form section div:not(#BlockOne) {
  padding: 15px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#BLockOne {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#environs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

label:hover,
label:active,
label:focus,
input:checked + label{
  background-color: white;
  color: #62BF67;
}

#environs>li>label {
  display: block;
}

#environs>li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<form>
  <section>
    <h3 class="header">Login information</h3>
    <div id="personal">
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email - first.last@email.com">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" id="firstpass" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

  </section>

  <section>
    <h3 class="header">One</h3>
    <div id="BlockOne">
      <input type="password" id="secpass" placeholder="Second Password">
      <ul id="environs">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="env" id="env1" value="env1"><label for="env1">env1</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="env" id="env2" value="env2"><label for="env2">env2</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="env" id="env3" value="env3"><label for="env3">env3</label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h3 class="header">Two</h3>
    <div id="BlockTwo">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Run">
</form>
```

What you can't do, is set the checkbox to checked using a hover event with CSS alone

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe my edits can clarify what I want - your answer is definitely the closest, and already looks great!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you organize your code well.
If you want to work with the fields checkbox, it would be preferable to create a container that will take the input and the label to avoid any bug.
The selector `+` retrieves the element that follows `immediately` input so if there is another element (for example a span) between the field and the label, then it will not work.
Then the selector `~` get the label preceded by an input, `be it immediately or have another element in between`.

```css
div.checkbox{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 8px;
}
div.checkbox > input{
  display: none;
}

div.checkbox > label{
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s;
}
div.checkbox > input:checked ~ label{
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="environ" value="env1" id="env1">
    <label for="env1">Chekbox item 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="env2" id="env2">
    <label for="env2">Chekbox item 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="environ" value="env3" id="env3">
    <label for="env3">Chekbox item 3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="environ" value="env4" id="env4">
    <label for="env4">Chekbox item 4</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what it does, either through text or comments in the code. If your answer is similar to an existing answer it should explain how it is different or how it improves on that answer.